# imputation using mice is showing error in parse

Tags: r, r-mice

This is the head of my dataset:

```
 head(new.data)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
      EIN `Number of Login~ `Last Login to the We~ Active_Particip~ Job_Position Tenure logTotalGamifica~ logPerformance
    <dbl>             <dbl>                  <dbl> <chr>            <chr>        <fct>              <dbl>          <dbl>
1   5370.               32.                    23. Yes              ASVCMG       5                   8.65          NA   
2 214801.               18.                     2. Yes              PTSSUP       1                   6.96          NA   
3 199908.               18.                    38. Yes              SVCADV       2                   8.01           4.19
4 212145.               20.                     2. Yes              SVCADV       1                   8.36          NA   
5   8917.                2.                    11. Yes              SVCTEC       4                   5.60          NA   
6   5204.                3.                    27. Yes              GENMGR       5                   7.31          NA   
# ... with 1 more variable: logCustomerViewPoint <dbl>
```

**I wanted to use multiple imputation using mice package using this code:**

```
exclude <- c( 'Total Gamification Point', 'Performance', 'Customer View Point')

include <- setdiff(names(Case.study.num), exclude)

new.data <- Case.study.num[include]

imp.new.data <- mice(new.data,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:16: unexpected symbol
1: EIN ~ 0+Number of
                   ^
```

Please give me some idea regarding what might be going wrong?

Comment: This seems easy to solve. Just rename the columns to valid syntax.

Comment: Hi Ronald! Could you please explain a little bit about the valid syntax? I have renamed the column names, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Valid names in R can't contain spaces. A few special characters that have specific meanings in R, such as the tilde, also aren't allowed in valid names.

Comment: Thank you so much Ronald! I think its working now

Comment: For future readers, you can always make use of the `make.names()` function within Base R to term any vector of strings into valid column name syntax.